# Trouble deploying cloud function -- stripe payment intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I have been looking at this and rewriting, and I don't know where I've gone wrong, but I cannot get this to deploy to firebase. I have been through a "Access to fetch at ... from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy" error.

When I follow the google docs to address the cors issue (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors), I get a failing to deploy error: Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.

Edit: Well, I'm lost on this one still. I have been running emulators and firebase serve and it's worked as a function. I just can't deploy it.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test");

exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (req, res) => {
    //set JSON content type and CORS headers for the response
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      // Send response to OPTIONS requests
      res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
      res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
      res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      res.status(204).send("");
    }

  try {
    const { codeItem } = req.body;

  //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
  
 const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: codeItem.num * codeItem.price * 100,
    currency: "usd",
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

  res.send({
    paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,

    success: true,
  });
} catch (error) {
  res.send({ success: false, error: error.message });
}
}
);
```

Comment: Have you tried  adding a response-type header `res.set('response-type', 'application/json');` to the response in the OPTIONS method

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not escaping all the text from your notation in the middle.

Try to replace it with:

```html
/*Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the 
    client */
```

Comment: Sorry -- that is just a stackoverflow thing. It is correct in the code. ill clarify in an edit